# Более частотный

Tags: выбор-слов, орфоэпия

Допустимо ли выражение: *Слово **более частотное**, чем другое слово*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вполне. Одно из значений этого слова - характеризующий частоту употребления, повторения чего-либо (словарь Ефремовой). Слово активно употреблялось преподавателями университета, еще когда я была студенткой.

Comment: А это профессиональный жаргон или термин?